# Wise algorithm to find difference between two strings

Tags: algorithm, diff, design-patterns

How do I print the difference between two strings. E.g. if given "abcde" and "xabcde" it should say "x" at the beginning. The different part could be anywhere, of course. Is there a standard algorithm for this?

Comment: replace all occurrences of "abcde" by ""?

Comment: What is your question exactly ? How to find if strings are substring of each other ? For example, what should be the result of the diff between `abcde` and `axbxcxdxex` ?

Comment: Or, for example, `ab` versus `ba`?

Comment: @WalterTross it is not "abcde" always.

Comment: Is the case where one isn't a substring of the other allowed? Such as "hello" and "jello"? And if so, what should the output be? "-h+j"? "h->j"? "hj"? Or something else?

Comment: Google levenshtein distance.

Comment: given 2 strings A and B: difference(A) = A - intersection(A,B), difference(B) = B - intersection(A,B)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there is any standard algorithm for this, but sure we can make one easily.

Create an integer array of 26 elements and declare all of them to zero in beginning.

```
int arr[26] = {0};
```

Let `arr[0]` represent number of a's, `arr[1]` represent number of b's....& so on.

Traverse string1 and increment respective array index for respective letter.

Traverse string2 and decrement respective array index for respective letter.

Now traverse your array and take absolute value present at each index of array

for eg.: if `arr[0] = 1`, take it as `1`; if `arr[1] = -2`, take it as `2`; if `arr[2] = 0`, take it as `0` & so on.

print out the respective letter that many times, for the eg. we took just now, you will have to print 'a' 1 time, 'b' 2 times, 'c' 0 times & so on.